# Charging internal laptop battery bypassing board

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, step-down

I own a refurbished tecrq z50a and during a routine clean up i did a mistake of taking off the bottom cover without realizing that it was still shutting down. A screw rolled on the board and sparks happened.

Notebook works using battery but battery wont charge, port is working and the local laptop shop has given up stating they cant get the current up to the correct voltage.

Is it possible for me to hijack the red\black wire from the battery pack and directly supply the correct voltage (maybe i would need to create some sort of step down from the laptop adaptor) so it will charge the battery while running the laptop or can i just replace the wires that is supposed to go to th battery with fixed wires. Its a shame if i have to throw this fairly good notebook away..

Any hints of a logical solution is appreciated,  as I am a programmer not a technician but I can learn the basics, thanks!

Comment: If the battery is a lithium battery, then there is almost certainly going to be a need for a suitable charge controller. It's not clear exactly which portion of the charging circuit has been damaged with the information provided, so I cannot give any further guidance. Remember that without a suitable charge control circuit (or controllable power supply and knowledge of the safe charging procedure), it is **highly unsafe** to charge lithium batteries due to risk of fire and damage to the cells.

Comment: So a safer option would be to modify those off the shelfs external laptop battery charger? That looks like a power brick with a custom pin connector directly to a battery pack

Comment: Modify, how? They are just power supplies so you would have to replicate the charging circuitry inside the laptop that actually charges the battery. Since it is a roughly 6 years old device, you could try finding a replacement motherboard if someone has broken a display. Or at least acquiring the laptop schematics to see if a simple part needs replacing. Without intimate knowledge of lithium batteries, you should not try to charge them with homebrew methods due to risk of fire and explosion.

Comment: something like this [Amazon Generic External Charger](https://www.amazon.com/Generic-External-Battery-Charger-BT-00603-111/dp/B00NLI9XM4) Would be a safe option? but I guess getting the schematics and learning would be a better choice? as a learning project. I assume everything should be repairable, at least for a notebook. perhaps just more man hour & part ordering ? Thanks

Comment: That generic external charger is not that generic and is listed as compatible for a certain set of battery part numbers, which may not include your battery. I can't really encourage repairing lithium battery charging circuitry on a motherboard (which is dense and sensitive to further damage) as a learning project.